# Determining proper order price on BTCe

Tags: btce, bots, exchange-order

I am writing a custom bot for trading at different Exchanges, while BTCe is the only one I have currently implemented to about 95%.

Now I am only hanging at one point: If my Bot decides to Sell/Buy, how can I determine the proper price for my order?

My Idea was to get the kist of current buy/sell oderders for e.g. BTC/USD and then calculate for which price I would have to sell/buy so the trade will be executed completely, but then I didn't find an API-method to get a list of current orders [here](https://btc-e.com/api/documentation).

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API call you are looking for is the market depth:

https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/depth

There are also calls for LTC/BTC

https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_btc/depth

and LTC/USD

https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/depth

All of the above return JSON data including both **ASKS** and **BIDS**

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can get info from http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/ for multi-exchange trade data.

For current market rate, 24-hour high/low, last, etc with btc-e you can use
https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker